# Which libraries should i use to make a telegram bot with python?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to send python script output to a telegram bot what libraries should I use and if possible how to use it.

I tried this but not working

```
import requests
def telegram_bot_sendtxt(bot_message):
    bot_token = "Bot_token"
    bot_chatID = "chat_id"
    send_txt = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + bot_token + "/sendMessage?chat_id= " + bot_chatID +  "&parse_mode=MarkdownV2&text=" + bot_message
    response = requests.get(send_txt)
    return response.json
telegram_bot_sendtxt("test")
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: you wanna send it through using message??

Answer (score 4):

See [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples#python). There are many libraries and code examples.

Answer (score 0):

Thy with this one: [Python Telegram Bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot)